# Create Pandas Dataframe from a List of Objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of objects that I would like to use to create a Pandas dataframe.

I'm new to Pandas but I thought this would work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(ddf_list, columns=['fixtureID', 'marketID', 'selectionID', 'competitorID'])
```

But it's not even close.

I can't find much information on doing this. Is it even possible? If so, how?

List:

```
ddf_list = [SelectionsForMarket(source_fixture_id='109040945', source_market_id='101609040945', source_market_type_id='10160', source_selection_id='10904094552946019', trading_status='NonRunner', name='Hulton Ranger', competitor_id='1052946019', ut=datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 9, 6, 30, 42, 149510), order=0, max_price=-1.0, prices=[]), SelectionsForMarket(source_fixture_id='109040945', source_market_id='101609040945', source_market_type_id='10160', source_selection_id='10904094552600648', trading_status='Trading', name='Yeeeaah', competitor_id='1052600648', ut=datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 9, 6, 30, 42, 149510), order=0, max_price=3.25, prices=[Price: 3.25, Bookmakers #:2, Price: 3.00, Bookmakers #:8]), SelectionsForMarket(source_fixture_id='109040945', source_market_id='101609040945', source_market_type_id='10160', source_selection_id='10904094553052373', trading_status='Trading', name='Helm Princess', competitor_id='1053052373', ut=datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 9, 6, 30, 42, 149510), order=0, max_price=3.75, prices=[Price: 3.75, Bookmakers #:8, Price: 3.40, Bookmakers #:1])]
```

Desired output:

| fixtureID | marketID | selectionID | competitorID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101609040945 | 10160 | 10904094552946000 | 1052946019 |
| 101609040945 | 10160 | 10904094552600600 | 1052600648 |
| 101609040945 | 10160 | 10904094553052300 | 1053052373 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert you class to `dataclass` which stores dict representation of the object, then all you have to do is loop to get `dict` of each object and transform into `dataframe`.

Here's how you can do it.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import datetime
from typing import List, Dict
import pandas as pd

@dataclass
class SelectionsForMarket:
    source_fixture_id: str
    source_market_id: str
    source_market_type_id: str
    source_selection_id: str
    trading_status: str
    name: str
    competitor_id: str
    ut: datetime
    order: int
    max_price: float
    prices: List[Dict]


ddf_list = [
    SelectionsForMarket(source_fixture_id='109040945', 
                        source_market_id='101609040945', 
                        source_market_type_id='10160', 
                        source_selection_id='10904094552946019', 
                        trading_status='NonRunner', 
                        name='Hulton Ranger', 
                        competitor_id='1052946019', 
                        ut=datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 9, 6, 30, 42, 149510), 
                        order=0, 
                        max_price=-1.0, 
                        prices=[]), 
    SelectionsForMarket(source_fixture_id='109040945', 
                        source_market_id='101609040945', 
                        source_market_type_id='10160', 
                        source_selection_id='10904094552600648', 
                        trading_status='Trading', 
                        name='Yeeeaah', 
                        competitor_id='1052600648', 
                        ut=datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 9, 6, 30, 42, 149510), 
                        order=0, 
                        max_price=3.25, 
                        prices=[{"Price": 3.25, "Bookmakers" :2}, 
                                {"Price": 3.00, "Bookmakers": 8}]), 
    SelectionsForMarket(source_fixture_id='109040945', 
                        source_market_id='101609040945', 
                        source_market_type_id='10160', 
                        source_selection_id='10904094553052373', 
                        trading_status='Trading', 
                        name='Helm Princess', 
                        competitor_id='1053052373', 
                        ut=datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 9, 6, 30, 42, 149510), 
                        order=0, 
                        max_price=3.75, 
                        prices=[{"Price": 3.75, "Bookmakers" :8}, 
                                {"Price": 3.40, "Bookmakers" :1}])]


required_columns = ["source_fixture_id", "source_market_id", "source_selection_id", "competitor_id"]
data = pd.DataFrame([x.__dict__ for x in ddf_list])[required_columns]
data
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
L = [{'fixtureID': x.SelectionsForMarket.source_fixture_id,
      'marketID': x.SelectionsForMarket.source_market_id,
      'source_selection_id': x.SelectionsForMarket.source_selection_id,
      'competitorID': x.SelectionsForMarket.competitor_id} for x in ddf_list]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael it gives me AttributeError: 'SelectionsForMarket' object has no attribute '_asdict'

Comment: @Robsmith - how working change `x._asdict()` to `dict(x)` ?

Comment: @Robsmith - If not working, can you try `[x.SelectionsForMarket.source_fixture_id for x in ddf_list]` if working for you?

Comment: @Robsmith - If yes, edited answer should working